# flexibility vs complexity vs number of predictors in machine learning

Tags: machine-learning, predictive-modeling, statistics, machine-learning-model, data-science-model

I'm new to machine learning so am quite confused with the above concepts. It seems to me both flexibility and complexity measures how well the model fit the data (in terms of the curvy-ness), so what's the difference between the two? In addition, I saw some websites say complexity can be indicated by the number of features in the model; but does 'feature' in this context mean variable, e.g. x and y (two variables), or term, e.g. x and x^2 (two terms), and is it different from 'predictor'? Also, I know flexibility can affect the generalization error, but except that, does flexibility affect any other aspects of model performance? Thanks for answering.

Comment: Can you include the sources that you refer to?

Comment: The website about complexity is this one: https://www.innoarchitech.com/blog/machine-learning-an-in-depth-non-technical-guide-part-3#:~:text=In%20machine%20learning%2C%20model%20complexity,learning%20complexity%20or%20computational%20complexity.

Comment: the 3 terms are not identical nevertheless they are related. For instance number fo predictors/features affects complexity, but there are complex functions to be found with only a few inputs. Flexibility relates to how easily the model can generalise and a very complex model may not be flexible, but again there is the other side of this

Comment: @NikosM. Thanks for replying. But could you maybe provide some examples for better illustration? I'm not totally sure that I understand the differences here.